# how to get location in gcmbaseintentservice

Tags: android, location, google-cloud-messaging, locationmanager

I want get the location when I receive a message.
So I used the GCM service but it does not work for LocationListener.
Is it possible to use LocationListener in GCMBaseIntentService? If not, what could I use instead?

Here is my source code:

```
@Override
public void onMessage(Context context, Intent intent) {
    String type = intent.getStringExtra("type");
    String fromId = intent.getStringExtra("fromId");
    String fromNumber = intent.getStringExtra("fromNumber");
    final String address;

    if(type.equals("request_position")){
        if( hasId(context, fromNumber)){
            Message message = new Message();
            message.obj = intent;
            MyService.handler.sendMessage(message);
        }else{
            String addressStr = "사용자의 친구가 아닙니다.";
            new SendMessage().execute("response_position",fromId,Info.get(context).getRegId(),addressStr);
        }
    }else if(type.equals("response_position")){
        address = intent.getStringExtra("address");

        Handler handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
        handler.post(new Runnable() {
             public void run() {
                  FindPhoneFragment.resultTv.setText(address);
             }
        });
    }


}



public class MyLocation {
private Context context;
private LocationManager manager;
private MyLocationListener listener;
private Location location;
private long minTime = 1000;
private float minDistance = 1;
private String fromId;

public MyLocation(Context context){
    this.context = context;
    manager = (LocationManager)context.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    listener = new MyLocationListener();
}
public void getMyLocation(String fromId){



    manager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, minTime, minDistance, listener);
    manager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, minTime, minDistance, listener);
 }
 public void sendLocation(Location location){

    Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(context ,Locale.KOREA);
    List<Address> address;

    Double latitude;
    Double longitude;
    latitude = location.getLatitude();
    longitude = location.getLongitude();
    String addressStr;

    try{
        if(geocoder !=null){
            address = geocoder.getFromLocation(latitude, longitude, 1);
            if(address != null && address.size() > 0){
                addressStr = address.get(0).getAddressLine(0).toString();
                new SendMessage().execute("response_position",fromId,Info.get(context).getRegId(),addressStr);
            }else{
                Log.d("GCM", "좌표없음");
            }
        }
    }catch(IOException e){
        //TODO
    }


}

class MyLocationListener implements LocationListener{
    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        sendLocation(location);
        manager.removeUpdates(listener);
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

}




}


public class Util {

private static Util sUtil;
private Context mAppContext;
private MyLocation myLocation;


private Util(Context appContext){
    mAppContext = appContext;
    myLocation = new MyLocation(appContext);
}


public static Util get(Context c){
    if(sUtil == null)
        sUtil = new Util(c.getApplicationContext());
    return sUtil;
}



public MyLocation getLocation(){
    return myLocation;
}

  }



public class MyService extends Service {
public static Handler handler = new Handler(){

    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        Intent intent = (Intent)msg.obj;
        onMessage( intent);
    }

    public void onMessage( Intent intent){
        String fromId =intent.getStringExtra("fromId");
        Util.get().getLocation().getMyLocation(fromId);
    }

};

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}
 }


  android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="21" />


 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/> 
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/> 
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>


<!-- GCM 권한 -->
<permission
    android:name="com.catcha.simplefindphone.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.catcha.simplefindphone.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />

<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE"/> 
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-feature android:glEsVersion="0x00020000" android:required="true"/>




<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity android:name="com.catcha.sfp.main.MainActivity" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name="com.catcha.sfp.main.MemberListActivity"></activity>
    <activity android:name="com.catcha.sfp.main.MapActivity"></activity>

    <!-- GCM 처리 서비스 -->

      <receiver
         android:name="com.google.android.gcm.GCMBroadcastReceiver" 
         android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />
        <category android:name="com.catcha.simplefindphone" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
    <service android:name=".GCMIntentService" />
    <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY" android:value="AIzaSyC7PbU9IsNdkwBb6w9uSBdPi-w0wXeRVBc"/>
    <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version"/>


</application>
```

Comment: Welcome RedMuffler! I edited your question a bit. If you disagree with my edit, you can roll it back. To do so, click on the "edited ... ago" link and look for the "rollback" option.

Comment: Can you post the entire class code? some variables are not defined properly, plus, is the getMyLocation function you posted is part of the Util class?

Comment: i reposted .. give me a hand..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IntentService is a service which remains active as long as it needed. In the GCM case it probably stops itself after processing the message. 
You can read more about it [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/IntentService.html).
If you register the IntentService as a listener for the location, when the locationManager is trying to invoke the listener it's no longer exists, meaning you don't get locations.


As for your code, I suggest you create a regular [Service](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html) which will operate in the background. When you receive a gcm message, you transfer it to the service and handle it there.
The way to transfer the message can be made by creating an Handler at the Service (not at the IntentService). The nice thing about handlers is that they execute code in the thread they have been created in. Meaning you will run your code in a context that is alive.

The gCMBaseIntentService class:

```
public class gCMBaseIntentService extends GCMBaseIntentService{
    public ActivityRecognitionIntentService() {
        super("ActivityRecognitionService");
    }

    @Override
    public void onMessage(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Message message = new Message();
        message.obj = intent;
        MyService.handler.sendMessage(message);
    }
}
```

The new Service:

```
public class MyService extends Service {
    public static Handler handler  = new Handler() {
            @Override
            public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
                Intent intent = (Intent) msg.obj;
                onMessage(this, intent);
            }
        };

    public void onMessage(Context context, Intent intent) {
        ... your original onMessage goes here ...
    }

}
```

Comment: i really appreciate for your kindness !!

Comment: but, i failed...
Success to fall in service, but just first time.. add never missing locationlistener

Comment: Can you be more specific on what you are experiencing?

Comment: I was impressed in your favor ToT
I made 'MyService'class and just applied
at result, MyService.handler.sendMessage(message) not work. except for the only only only first one.
i'm sorry about that could you please give me a example??... because i think, it needs to compare. i'm sorry to bother you

Comment: can you edit the question again, add an "update" section and post your entire new code there? (including your androidmanifest.xml).
Thanks.

Comment: you need to register your service in the manifest, something like

    <service android:name=".MyService" />

try to change minTime and minDistance to 0. if it works play with them later.

in your MyLocationListener class, add a print on the onLocationChanged method and see if you get any locations at all.

Comment: Oh thanks a lot
it's successful to service part, but locatinlistener still not work.. it seems like core problem in my source... :(

Comment: you need to isolate the problem? did you ever managed to make location requests work? if not try this tutorial and see if you get locations. http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidLocationAPI/article.html

Comment: sure, location requests is no problem to me. but it's difficult to get the location on GCMBaseIntentService.. I'd like know why fail this situation(GCMBaseIntentService!!!!!!!!!!!!!@#!@#!@#!).
I have not yet solved the problem, but i felt thankful enough for you :)

Comment: on the onMessage() method at the handler, you call the Util singelton without sending him Context. he later on calls the requestLocation with an invalid context. try to transfer the MyService context (possible by using "this") to the singelton and use that context to start the locationRequests.

Comment: that means 'use mylocation by using this' right?
but it calls error when use 'this' because onMessage have context parameter. can it call Context in handleMessage? I guess, they not match this and context.. do you understand to my explanation?
eclips recommends to change 'Context' type to 'Handler' type

Comment: Take the onMessage method out of the Handler body and put it directly under the MyService class

Comment: I tried that but it's not still disappear to problem.
This part of The new service (MyService class) calls error. 
do you try that? could you show your demo source ?
and Merry Christmas ~ ! :)

Comment: if parameter of onMessage()method is Context Type, eclipse recommends change to Handler type. summing-up, 'this' of handdleMessage()method can't calls Context Type..
can you this source what you post ?